# Componete Popover - Submit não funciona

Tags: javascript, html

Olá!

Tenho o seguinte popover, mas ao acionar o submit, nada acontece.

Podem me ajudar ?

```js
$(function() {
        $('a[rel=popover]').popover({
        html: 'true',
  title: 'Título popover',
    placement: 'right',
    content : function() {
        return $('#popover-content').html();
    }
    });
});

$(document).on('click', 'button#abrir', function () {
    $('a[rel=popover]').popover('show');
});
```

```html
<a rel="popover" role="button" id="abrir" class="btn btn-default btn-flat" title="Título" >
 <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>       
</a>

<div id="popover-content" style="display: none" >
 <div class="row">
  <form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="pagina_teste.php">
      <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
          <label for="nome">Nome</label>
       <input type="text" id="nome" name="nome" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" autofocus placeholder="Nome" value="<?php echo set_value('nome'); ?>" >
   </div>
   <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
          <label for="validade">Validade</label>
       <input type="text" id="validade" name="validade" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" autofocus placeholder="00/00/00000" value="<?php echo set_value('validade'); ?>" >
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-12" style="">
       <div class="input-group pull-left" >
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-flat pull-left">
         <i class="fa fa-check"></i>          
        </button>
          </div>
    <div class="input-group pull-right" style="">
      <button type="button" id="fechar" class="btn btn-default btn-flat" rel="popover">
      <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
        </button>
                </div>
      </div>
  </form>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Qual biblioteca você tá usando para o popover?

Comment: Para o código que coloquei aqui, não utilizei nenhuma biblioteca a não ser o .js

Mas fiz tambem através do plugin *boostrap popover x*.
http://demos.krajee.com/popover-x

E não consegui tambem!

Comment: @WagnerFilho você sabe que o Bootstrap depende do jQuery, certo? Está incluindo a biblioteca jQuery antes do script do Bootstrap?

Comment: @Renan, Isto só foi no exemplo mas no projeto que estou desenvolvendo!
A biblioteca jQuery está sendo chamada depois.

Comment: @WagnerFilho ok, há algum erro no console?

Comment: @Renan, nada aparece!

Comment: Tente criar um exemplo reproduzível então, porque testei e funcionou normalmente: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/busttzuj/).

Comment: @Renan, uma dúvida!
Muda alguma coisa, se o objeto for criado em um modal ?
Pois o mesmo código não funciona no modal, mas em uma página em branco, funcionou.